# Starting with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql

I'm having major difficulties to start off with NHiberante.

Main problems:

Where my hbm.xml files should reside? I create a Mappings folder but I received an error "Could not find xxx.hbm.xml file."

I tried to load the specific class through the dialect cf.AddClass(typeof(xxx)); but it still gives me the same error (the files are marked as embebed resources.

Also I'm having major problems in connection to it. I stopped trying to use the cfg xml file and tried a more direct approach with a library I have here.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.AddClass(typeof(Tag));

        ISessionFactory sessions = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        AgnosticConnectionHandler agch = new AgnosticConnectionHandler("xxx","xxx","geo_biblio","localhost",
            5432,DatabaseInstance.PostgreSQL);
        ISession sessao = sessions.OpenSession(agch.GetConnection);

        ITransaction tx = sessao.BeginTransaction();

        Tag tag1 = new Tag();
        tag1.NomeTag = "Teste Tag NHibernate!!!";

        sessao.Save(tag1);
        tx.Commit();
        sessao.Close();
```

Any tips for me? I'm getting the exception in line 2 of this code, and still not sure what to do.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the error description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting with nHibernate I think you **really** should take a look at [fluent nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/), its way easier do develop and maintain the mapping, it even has an auto-mapping option.

Another option is [confORM](http://code.google.com/p/codeconform/) from [Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com) (nhibernate lead developer), looks like a great tool.

Also, you can take a look at [s#arp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/), you can get some nice ideas from this project.

Comment: I put an effort at NHibernate and I got it working for a very simple mapping. Thank you both for your help and i WILL definitively look at FNH